# Unable to load @webpack-cli/serve

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack-cli

I downloaded a project folder from a pluralsight tutorial, when I try to run it with npm start it shows this message:

> [webpack-cli] Unable to load '@webpack-cli/serve' command
> [webpack-cli] TypeError: options.forEach is not a function
> at WebpackCLI.makeCommand (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:173:21)
>
> ```
> at ServeCommand.apply (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:41:19)
>
> at loadCommandByName (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:907:35)
> at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1462:17)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async WebpackCLI.run (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1500:9)
>
> at async runCLI (C:\Users\Israel Juarez\Desktop\before\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js:11:9)
> ```
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! ps-redux@1.0.0
> start: `webpack serve --config webpack.config.dev.js --port 3000` npm
> ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the ps-redux@1.0.0
> start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
> is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Israel
> Juarez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-20T17_42_05_820Z-debug.log

Comment: This is being discussed here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2990

Answer (score 21):

You would betther uninstall your version of webpack-cli by:
npm uninstall webpack-cli

Then - bump your version of webpack-cli by:
npm install webpack-cli --save-dev

That might help. Also check you don't have @webpack-cli/serve in package.json directly.

Answer (score 1):

from the authors comment on the issue:

> Looks like we have small regression here, but if we revert it, it will
> create another breaking change, so my recommendation - bump
> webpack-cli@4.9.0 and update lock file, also check you don't have
> @webpack-cli/serve in package.json directly.
>
> Sorry for this

I changed the version from 4.5.0 to 4.9.0 and it the dev server starts as expected.

Thanks to [@Henry Story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650809/unable-to-load-webpack-cli-serve#comment126820117_70818341) for the issue [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2990).

Answer (score 0):

run these commands

- npm install webpack
- npm install --save-dev webpack-cli

Hope the issue will get resolved.

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Add `mode: 'development'` into your config file.

```
module.exports = {
     mode: 'development',
     ...
    };
```

OR

type CLI argument and verify on file:

```
webpack --mode=development
```

Also, you can either choose 'development', 'production' or 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem in my project. In my case, I first delete `package-lock.json` both in `root` and `./node_modules` directory, then run the following code

> npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps webpack-cli@4.9.0

This error happens to be related to the version of `webpack-cli` used in projects.